# CircleCollider2D is not registering collisions with some tiles in a TileMapCollider2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

(I've asked this question over at Unity Answers too, but it can sometimes take a while to get a response there, if I get an answer there I'll put it here too.)

I'm making a tile based game that uses Grid > Tilemap with cell layout as Hexagon.

The player can move a certain distance based on movement level. My plan is to highlight valid movement spaces in green and invalid in red. To do this I've got a child GameObject called MovementRange that has a CircleCollider2D attached with it's radius matching the player's movement level. All settings as default.

The TileMap uses a TileMapCollider2D. As each tile on the grid is smaller than the actual grid hexagon this means that each tile is separated by a gap. The TileMapCollider2D correctly assigns each tile a hexagonal collider. All settings as default. The tilemap also has a Rigidbody2D set as Kinematic and Use Full Kinematic Contacts checked.

This is the function used to highlight the tiles in range:

```
void HighlightCellsInRange(Collision2D collision)
 {
     Vector3 hitPosition = Vector3.zero;
     ContactPoint2D[] contacts = new ContactPoint2D[100];
     int contactCount = collision.GetContacts(contacts);

     for (int i = 0; i < contactCount; i++)
     {
         Vector3Int tile = _tileMap.WorldToCell(contacts[i].point);
         _tileMap.SetTile(tile, _greenTile);
         _tilesInRange.Add(tile);
     }
 }
```

This works correctly for any tile that a collision is registered for. The problem is that some tiles don't register collisions (and others have multiple collisions).

Here are some screen shots where you can see what's happening:

I have generated gizmo spheres at all of the collision contacts returned. The circle collider is selected so you can see that clearly there are missing tile collision contact points. There's 6 missing in the very center of the circle collider!

[image: CircleCollider2D missing contacts]

In this screen shot you can see the grid and that every tile is displaying active hexagonal colliders.

[image: TilemapCollider2D tiles colliders]

I've tried changing the settings on the circle collider and the tilemap collider but I can't understand why some of the collisions are not registering.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Up until very recently there have been some bugs with 2D colliders not reporting some collisions. It might be as recent as 2018.3.x late betas (last few weeks) that finally almost completely fixed this. If you can, update to the latest 18.3.x beta, and see if you get the same problem. Please... PLEASE backup your project before opening it in 2018.3 betas... as you won't be able to reopen it in 18.2 versions afterwards. I got caught once, with this. It's a nightmare.

Comment: Hi @Confused, thanks for your response. That's interesting, I've downloaded 18.3b to see if there is a difference in the calculations. If not I'll file a bug report. I have a work around I'm using at the moment which rotates and checks the tiles a set distance at every 12 degrees. It works but it's not pretty.

Comment: Afraid the problem still exists. It appears the individual tile colliders in a tilemapcolldier2d are not currently implemented to allow correct collision points. They currently allow physical collision, to prevent colliders passing through them, but it appears not this use case. I'll file a bug report. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could try using a collider as a trigger, and then checking for stay... that might work more reliably... The oddness of collision reports not reporting plagued me for most of this year, I wasn't aware of the bug and couldn't imagine it was bugged, so tried a million other things thinking it was my fault. It wasn't. Which is unusual ;) I've dome to learn that Unity has a lot of little annoying bugs that you wouldn't expect to be in something that claims to be so incredibly popular.

Comment: @Confused, I had already tried Trigger Colldiers I'm afraid, the problem is that they only return a Collider2D object not a Collision2D object, the collider2d doesn't have any info on contact points. The tilemapcolldier2d is only a single collider so I just get a hit on the entirety of the Tilemap ... which isn't very useful!

Comment: You must have the patience of a god. I just tried the hexagonal tile map. There is no doubt that Unity is un-design led. I wanted to reach through the monitor and throttle every member of their staff and management.

Comment: What units are the tile maps sizes in, relative to pixels? Say, for example, in your endeavour, what does x:1 and y:1.2 turn out to as a pixel sized hexagon? I was going to try build something like what you're doing, but there's no apparent scaling mechanisms for graphics, so I have to build them first, to the exact desired size, when I don't yet know what that size is. This is the kind of 'genius' un-design I've come to expect from Unity. But it's no less infuriating the 50th time I've come across it in something they've added to the bullet point feature lists.

Comment: And I fully understand your issues with colliders as triggers versus as colliders. I've resorted to using one of each on my key objects. One as a trigger, which is a bit larger, and then the colliding object for impact events and the like, with details. It works, but it took days to find a way to make it efficient and effective.

Comment: After looking at this more closely, I'm not sure TileMaps are what you should use in unity. The lack of binding between the physics shapes and their respective grid position is BULLSHIT!

Comment: @Confused, thanks for your continued interest! I think I read a response from a unity dev somewhere that the tilemap physics objects are not calculated in the same way as usual ones (as they would be too expensive), but I can't find the post anymore. The hexagon tiles' pixel size is based on the import settings of the sprite. I think mine are 120 x 108 but I squashed them slightly. (You'll notice as you adjust the grid cell size though that it's orientation is based on the cell swizzle. So Y is actually horizontal with the standard YXZ cell layout!).

Comment: I had considered using individual sprites for each tile, in order to calculate their collision point properly, but this felt like hacking a system together when a system designed for this purpose is right there. You can download the project I sent with my bug report here if you're interested: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlQDzTq2dTgSvFa008t-kfS3Vt9x

Comment: I previously built a hexagon grid system for my game, all sorts of rollovers for scoring. And was going to make it a tile map, eventually. I've now changed my mind. It's too bothersome. I'll just make a entry and exit trigger that turns on and off all the hexagon colliders/physics bodies so it's not too expensive when not needed. Generally speaking, the 2D physics system is FAST! Probably the second fastest and lightest part of Unity, after the particles. Which are quite good! So you shouldn't worry about numbers of objects. I have thousands on an iPad game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up sending a bug report to Unity, which they accepted (eventually).

They first tried to explain it as "It doesn't fire if the collider is already over the object". Which it wasn't anyway, and doesn't explain why the other tiles were still collided with.
So I screen recorded a collider growing from 0.1 radius to full size and tracking the contact points with gizmos the entire time. You could clearly see the contact points starting out fine, then suddenly disappearing, especially on the right hand side of the tilemap as it grew.

So as it stands, collision against individual tiles is not reliable with TilemapCollider2D when the collider contacts more than a few tiles simultaneously.

Here's a GIF of the bug for those interested:
[image]

Comment: Same bug here with unity 2019.1. Hope it gets fixed soon.