# Detect which Tilemap cells have collided with a Collider2D in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I have a `Tilemap`. This has a `TilemapCollider2D` component. Onto this are painted several tiles that each have their own sprite collider shape. However they are sprite tiles not prefabs. (They were not painted using the Prefab Brush.)

I also have a game object with a `Collider2D` (a `CircleCollider2D` in my case) with `isTrigger` set to `true` and no `Rigidbody2D` attached as this game object stays at a fixed position relative to its parent.

*[EDIT: I discovered that this collider is actually using the `Rigidbody2D` of the parent game object. Without any rigid body, collisions wouldn't be detected at all.]*

When the `Collider2D` enters/exits a tile, how can I identify the grid coordinates (`Vector3Int`) of that tile?

To be clear, I want to detect this from the Tilemap script. i.e. `TilemapCollider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D()` or `TilemapCollider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D()`.

For example, in the picture below, I would want to have received `OnTriggerEnter2D()` for tiles B, C, D & E and to know their positions in the grid.

[image: Circle collider overlapping with tiles B, C, D & E]

Comment: Would e.g. this help? https://answers.unity.com/questions/1572343/how-to-detect-on-which-exact-tile-a-collision-happ.html

Comment: @derHugo Yes I'd looked at that but it was doing things from the perspective of the circle object detecting, rather than the tilemap so I wasn't sure it was applicable, and I wanted to avoid the raycasting route if possible.I've done more experimenting and... I discovered that my circle collider was automatically making use of the parent's Rigidbody2D, which I wasn't expecting, but it explains why collision/trigger detecting has been happening.

Comment: I followed those instructions and made both colliders `isTrigger=false` and I had to put them on special layers with different layer collision settings in Project Settings > Physics 2D to avoid other objects getting stuck on these tiles. This has resulted in OnCollisionEnter2D working, but behaviour is sporadic. On first contact, e.g. with tiles C & D, I get immediate collisions, but it's only when the circle reaches two grid squares lower that I get collisions for all the other tiles. Weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird behaviour related to this bug perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462798/circlecollider2d-is-not-registering-collisions-with-some-tiles-in-a-tilemapcolli Or is there a more sane explanation and solution?

Comment: Just to wrap up these comments, I got an excellent explanation of the weird behaviour from a couple of the folks at Unity. https://forum.unity.com/threads/weird-behaviour-on-tilemapcollider2d.1012402/

Comment: Somehow your question here does in no way reflect what you have asked there ;) Here it was only about getting certain trigger methods called .. not really about why contact points are off

Comment: That's true. I asked the questions there to get a fuller understanding of what I was seeing as weird behaviour. I think the main thing that distinguishes my question from the one you referenced is that that one is looking for initial entry contact position whereas I am interested in entry & exit for each tile. Based on this I now have a solution which I'm in the process of posting as an answer. I'd welcome your comments (or your own solution too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this question covers not just the collision between the `Collider2D` and the `TilemapCollider2D`, but between the `Collider2D` and **each tile**, it is not as simple as detecting the collision between the colliders.

([Simple detection of collision between the colliders is covered in this question on answers.unity.com.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1572343/how-to-detect-on-which-exact-tile-a-collision-happ.html))

For the tilemap script to detect the entry and exit of each tile, it needs to respond to `OnTriggerEnter2D()`, `OnTriggerStay2D()` & `OnTriggerExit2D()`.

Here is my solution based on detecting when a `CircleCollider2D` intersects with each tile, not taking into account the geometry of any collider within the tiles. The intersections are an approximation (for efficiency) and may need adapting for other types of `Collider2D`.

### Overview

Within `OnTriggerEnter2D()`, get the bounding box of the `CircleCollider2D` and from that identify which tiles it intersects with.

For each of those tiles, get the world position of `CircleCollider2D` that is closest to that tile's centre. If that world position is within the tile, then there is an intersection. As well as handling this as desired, also add this tile's coordinates to a tracking list.

Within `OnTriggerStay2D()`, do the same as `OnTriggerEnter2D()` but remove from the tracking list those tiles that no longer intersect and handle their intersection exits.

Within `OnTriggerExit2D()` the two colliders have separated, so handle intersection exits for all tiles in the tracking list and clear the tracking list.

### Code example

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; // needed for cloning the list with .ToList()
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps; // needed for Tilemap

public class MyTilemapScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<Vector3Int> trackedCells;
    Tilemap tilemap;
    GridLayout gridLayout;

    void Awake()
    {
        trackedCells = new List<Vector3Int>();
        tilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        gridLayout = GetComponentInParent<GridLayout>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // NB: Bounds cannot have zero width in any dimension, including z
        var cellBounds = new BoundsInt(
            gridLayout.WorldToCell(other.bounds.min),
            gridLayout.WorldToCell(other.bounds.size) + new Vector3Int(0, 0, 1));

        IdentifyIntersections(other, cellBounds);
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // Same as OnTriggerEnter2D()
        var cellBounds = new BoundsInt(
            gridLayout.WorldToCell(other.bounds.min),
            gridLayout.WorldToCell(other.bounds.size) + new Vector3Int(0, 0, 1));

        IdentifyIntersections(other, cellBounds);
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // Intentionally pass zero size bounds
        IdentifyIntersections(other, new BoundsInt(Vector3Int.zero, Vector3Int.zero));
    }

    void IdentifyIntersections(Collider2D other, BoundsInt cellBounds)
    {
        // Take a copy of the tracked cells
        var exitedCells = trackedCells.ToList();

        // Find intersections within cellBounds
        foreach (var cell in cellBounds.allPositionsWithin)
        {
            // First check if there's a tile in this cell
            if (tilemap.HasTile(cell))
            {
                // Find closest world point to this cell's center within other collider
                var cellWorldCenter = gridLayout.CellToWorld(cell);
                var otherClosestPoint = other.ClosestPoint(cellWorldCenter);
                var otherClosestCell = gridLayout.WorldToCell(otherClosestPoint);

                // Check if intersection point is within this cell
                if (otherClosestCell == cell)
                {
                    if (!trackedCells.Contains(cell))
                    {
                        // other collider just entered this cell
                        trackedCells.Add(cell);

                        // Do actions based on other collider entered this cell
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // other collider remains in this cell, so remove it from the list of exited cells
                        exitedCells.Remove(cell);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Remove cells that are no longer intersected with
        foreach (var cell in exitedCells)
        {
            trackedCells.Remove(cell);

            // Do actions based on other collider exited this cell
        }
    }
}
```

### FYI

[From a separate discussion on forum.unity.com](https://forum.unity.com/threads/weird-behaviour-on-tilemapcollider2d.1012402/), I learned a couple of important points (that weren't obvious to me):

1. For a `TilemapCollider2D`, `OnTriggerEnter2D()` & `OnTriggerExit2D()` are invoked at the level of the whole `TilemapCollider2D`, not at a per-tile level. i.e. just like any other collider type.
2. `Collision2D.contacts` is an array of `ContactPoint2D`. `ContactPoint2D.point` is described as "The point of contact between the two colliders in world space." which implies to me that it is the point of intersection. However, it is actually the location at which the physics model wants to apply force. As a result, my solution uses trigger colliders and `OnTriggerXxxx` instead of `OnCollisionXxxx` and I work out the intersections myself.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the set up you have, but I would suggest trying the colliders on the letter objects, they are children of the tile map right?

I have set up like this:

Tilemap

-A - has colider2d and rigidbody2d

-B - has colider2d and rigidbody2d

-C - has colider2d and rigidbody2d

-D - has colider2d and rigidbody2d

Circle - has circle collider2d and a circle script

the following is in the circle script and gives the exact trigger object

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    Debug.Log($"touched {collider.name}");
}
```

just note that you need at least one rigidbody to get a trigger but you can swap from the letters to the circle if you need.

Comment: I shall make my question clearer: The tiles with letters on them are not prefabs; i.e. they were not painted with the Prefab Brush, so they are not children of Tilemap. This is intentional as I want to benefit from Tilemap which has a single GameObject, whereas using Prefabs would result in one GameObject per tile. The question I'm asking relates to TilemapColldier2D.OnTriggerEnter2D()

Comment: I am not that familiar with tile maps, but if not painted or even without children, how did you separate various tiles? just need to know how is your set up if I try to help.

Comment: did you check derHugo comment? is it something similar?