# Delete tiles when colliding with them

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to delete a tile whenever my player is colliding with it. I can delete the tile with mouseclick by this script

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

Vector3Int position = dirtGrid.WorldToCell(mousePos);

dirtTilemap.SetTile(position, null);
```

However i want the players collider to collide with the tile and then get that tiles position to delete the tile :)

If anyone has any idea please feel free to tell me!

Comment: Make every tile to store its position and a reference to the tilemap that contains them. Then add [collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) method to the tile, and in that method the tile should invoke stored tilemap's method that deletes the tile at stored position

Comment: Since the tilemap has the tiles in them,and the tilemap collider is only triggering once, i am only colliding once. I would like all of the tiles in front of the player to be removed. How could i make them store their position by the way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so I'll have to direct you to this other question with an answer. I've tried to work with individual tile collisions before as well and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64976889/detect-which-tilemap-cells-have-collided-with-a-collider2d-in-unity).

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @gru Are you referring to the linked post or to my post? I would have sent the link as a comment, but I am a newly active user and can't write comments on other's posts yet. Please copy the link into a comment for me and I will remove this answer.

Comment: @BaconNugget Thanks for the comment and answer! And disregard Gru's comment, just negative and besserwisser.
I changed the solution to remove times when clicking the mouse. Works fine :)